# How to increment variable by using same variable?

Tags: counters, pgfmath

How can I increment variable from the same variable?

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\S{5};
\pgfmathsetmacro\S{\S + 1};%   not working
```

How can I work around this? I need counters which I use as line coordinates increment in certain conditions.

**Update**

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\cA{0}; 
\newcounter{cB}
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}
{ 
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\cA{\cA+1)};
    \pgfmathaddtocounter{cB}{1};            
    \node at (\x,1) { \cA };
    \node at (\x,0) { \the\numexpr\value{cB} };         
}
```

printed out this

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I need

```
1 2 3 4 ...
```

Yes, I could do this in this simple example by just using `\x` variable but in my real diagram I need to increment them irregularly. So I need variable which can be incremented inside the loop without resets. Or, am I missing something and it should work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be used in a `\foreach` loop, there are better options:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [count=\S from 5] in {1,...,5}
    \node [draw, xshift=\i cm] {\S};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

where the syntax `count=\S from 5` is used here to set `\S` to `5` and advance it by `1` in each iteration. Another syntax may be `evaluate=\i as \S using \i+4`, which will achieve the same result.

**Update**

The increment can be changed within the loop based on a condition like this:

```
\newcounter{cA} 
\setcounter{cA}{0}
\newcounter{cB}
\setcounter{cB}{0}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}{ 
    \addtocounter{cA}{1}
    \ifnum\x<6\addtocounter{cB}{1}\else\addtocounter{cB}{2}\fi            
    \node at (\x,1) { \thecA };
    \node at (\x,0) { \thecB };          
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: ok, thx.. but value is reset when foreach loop increments, any workaround for that?

Comment: @Martin877  - The `\pgfmathsetcounter` should be placed before the loop so as not to be reset.

Comment: i got that idea..i created counter and first set of pgfmacros before loop  but that doesn't help, still resets when i inc them inside loop. I need to increment numerous times these variables in loop otherwise its pointless. Is there any counter which doesnt get reset, besides foreach variables?

Comment: @Martin877 - What do you mean by _besides foreach variables_? In my update, `\S` is not the loop counter and it can start from any value and can also be incremented/decremented by any value. What exactly are your requirements?

Comment: edited question

Answer (score 9):

No need to use `pgf` math for counters. You can just use `\setcounter`, `\stepcounter` or `\addtocounter`.  Using these, the counter value is retained after the `\foreach` loop:

[image]

Not sure I fully understand the intent code snippet given, but can easy be adapted to use TeX counters as well (as shown in the second MWE below):

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{foo}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{foo}{0}
    After \verb|\setcounter|: foo=\arabic{foo}

    \stepcounter{foo}
    After \verb|\stepcounter|: foo=\arabic{foo}

    \addtocounter{foo}{4}
    After \verb|\addtocounter|: foo=\arabic{foo}

    \foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
        \stepcounter{foo}%
    }%
    After \verb|\foreach|: foo=\arabic{foo}
\end{document}
```

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{cA}
\newcounter{cB}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,10} {%
        \stepcounter{cA};
        \stepcounter{cB};            
        \node at (\x,1) { \the\value{cA} };
        \node at (\x,0) { \the\value{cB} };         
    }        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

It works with pgf 3.0.1a:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfmathsetmacro\S{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro\S{\S + 1}

\begin{document}
\S
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- `\pgfmathsetmacro` is not a path command, therefore its syntax does not know a closing semicolon. In the preamble the additional semicolon causes an error (Missing `\begin{document}`).
- If you want to have an integer as result, then `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` helps:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{pgf}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\S{5}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\S{\S + 1}

  \begin{document}
  \S
  \end{document}
  ```

  > [image: Result with \pgfmathtruncatemacro]

Comment: Does that also work within an animateinline environment?

Comment: It seems, \multiframe is resetting the value to its outer scope value.